# Playing a tone with specific frequency in either left or right headphone

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, avaudioplayer, audiokit

I would like to know if there is any way that one can generate an audio tone of a specific frequency and play it through plugged in headphones on either the right or left side of the headphones. Is there any possible was to do this with code or a module such as AudioKit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just use the AKOscillator node:

https://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKOscillator.html

to create the frequency:

```
var osc = AKOscillator()
osc.frequency = 440 // or whatever
```

and then use an AKPanner node:

https://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKPanner.html

and

https://audiokit.io/playgrounds/Basics/Stereo%20Panning/

And set the `pan` to `-1` for left and `1` for right:

```
var panner = AKPanner(osc)
panner.pan = -1 // or 1
```